# How to access HTML code from a different page on a website with the same url as the original page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Essentially, my problem is how to access the HTML code for the third page on this website in Python. https://sdat.dat.maryland.gov/RealProperty/Pages/default.aspx

My objective is to open the link, select the appropriate county and search method, click next, enter the street number and street name, then select the appropriate record, and finally extract information from this record, all in Python. I am getting all this information from an excel spreadsheet.

Thus far, I have figured out how to select the county and search method, and enter the street number and name. I cannot figure out how to select the appropriate record. My approach was to get the HTML code for this page and then use a regular expression to click on the appropriate record based on the information in the excel spreadsheet. Whenever I try to get the HTML code from the site, I get the code from the original website, and not the page I am trying to get it from.

So for example, I would select Baltimore County, search by Street Address, type in 2414 Rockwell, but then I cannot figure out how to click on the appropriate record.

Any help would be appreciated! Additionally, if anyone has other suggestions on how to approach this problem, that would also be appreciated!

Comment: Since you have to enter details in a few fields and make a few clicks before you get the results page, I would suggest you to use Selenium. You can use python and selenium to automate such activities and finally when you get to your target page you can either use Selenium or BeautifulSoup to do the rest of the data-scraping.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am currently using Selenium, and I used Selenium to enter all the information, select from drop-downs, etc. I am just not sure how I could use Selenium to choose a specific record based on the information provided in the Excel sheet. For example, if the spreadsheet said to grab the information for a guy name "John Smith," I would need to click on the record "John Smith."

Comment: I found another post with a very similar problem, except mine is in Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733392/vba-extract-html-from-new-page-same-url

Comment: If you must click then use Selenium to execute the click after you search the element in question. But do expand the page source and see if you can grab it as an html. If all you want is in an html table, sometimes you could directly load in that html table into a pandas data frame and then select whatever you want.

Comment: Please share some code as well.